# AWS Instance default domain user

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ami, amazon-ec2

We've created a custom Windows server AMI for our build slave machines in AWS and we want to call up multiple instances of this AMI using Jenkins. For the username and password field in jenkins, we've been using Administrator and the default password given at the time of AMI creation.

However, what if we want to use a domain user that we've set up within our VPC? Let's call that user DOMAIN\user, which is an administrative user that was part of the custom AMI creation within windows.

So my question is, how do we use DOMAIN\user instead of Administrator to call up these instances?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be a Jenkins issue after all.

What we needed to use in the Jenkins EC2 plugin user field was svcUser@DOMAIN.AWS as opposed to DOMAIN.AWS\svcUser. Didn't like the backslash.